# "В принципе" - зачем оно контексту/тексту и обособлять ли?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> В общении я часто знаю, как и чем всё закончится. Это моя профессия. Я
>   смотрю на человека и чётко представляю, что у него произошло *до*. Что
>   будет *после*. И как он спит, и как выглядит, когда ест, и почему
>   смотрит на тебя… Но всю информацию, которую я, в принципе, собираю —
>   вечером отдаю зрителям. Всё по-честному: за что покупаю, за то и
>   продаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, автор таким образом пытается обозначить, что в ходе общения (видимо, с интервьюируемым) собирает информацию, а  остальное (что дальше будет с собеседником, на трамвайном ли пути) - не принципиально. Но воспринимается это как малозначащая присказка, лучше заменить чем-то ("в силу своей профессии", "целенаправленно", "только и" и т. п.).

Comment: Вопрос: обособлять ли здесь ***в принципе***? Увидела у себя совсем уж лишнюю запятую перед *я* - убираю.

Comment: Поскольку здесь не приписать смысл "из принципа" (без обособления), то выглядит это вводным сочетанием с извинительным значением "вообще говоря" - если оставлять, видимо, надо и обособлять.